# Everytime I want to clear the browser data then only website shows their output in nopcommerce 4.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies, browser, browser-cache, nopcommerce-4.0

I am developing theme in **nopcommerce 4.0**, now at view(MVC) if I change any design thing and run the website at that time website not showing the design according to the design code but at the simultaneously when I clear the **browser data** and after that run the website it shows the output design according to the design code.

So, from this I want to clear **browser data** again and again and then run the website. So, from that my time also wasting as well as whatever I saved the important thing in browser cookies that also removed.

So, is there any solution that I dont want to do clear **browser data** again and again and run the website and get the output design according to the design code.

Comment: It would be more better to check, which specific data causing the issue, cache, cookie?

Answer (score -1):

I got the solution. If we click the **ctrl + F5** then this type of issue not found.